# books/articles/dissertations/etc about odd time meters history/theory?

Tags: jazz, time-signatures

I'm working on my graduate thesis in jazz drumming. I chose odd time signatures as the main feature of my work, so i'm looking for some sources from which i can pick up some concepts and draw some teachings. Do you have any advice? Thank you.

Michele

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for off-site resources is off-topic.